# gcc compiles 16 bit real time code with -m16 option

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, stack

I'm doing some practices with real time code using `gcc -m16` option, but I find that if I make the argument or return type of a function `int16_t` type, still `%eax` or something 32 bits in stack will be use. But I donot want it to perform like this, that's to say, just do it bit for bit, no alignment in function call or anywhere else, is it any method?

detail:

```
zhang@HP-deepin:~/Desktop/tmp$ cat c.c
#include <stdint.h>

int16_t small(int16_t a, int16_t b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
zhang@HP-deepin:~/Desktop/tmp$ gcc -m16 -S -O3 c.c -o c.s
zhang@HP-deepin:~/Desktop/tmp$ cat c.s
    .file   "c.c"
    .code16gcc
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  small
    .type   small, @function
small:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %edx
    movl    8(%esp), %eax
    cmpw    %dx, %ax
    cmovg   %edx, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   small, .-small
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 6.2.0-11) 6.2.0 20161103"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: `but I find`... so, like, how did you find?  Would you like to share your research?

Comment: gcc cannot actually generate real 16 bit code. With `-m16`, it generates the same code as in 32 bit mode but with some adjustments to run in 16 bit mode. If you want to learn from compiler output, use a proper 16 bit compiler.

Comment: @fuz maybe you're right, util now I cannot find a solution for it. I heard that gcc 7 will have some improvement fot 16 bit code, hope it.

Comment: @AsyncCode : Highly doubtful GCC will support true 16-bit code anytime in the near future. I'd recommend [OpenWatcom](https://github.com/open-watcom) which still supports true 16-bit code generation.