# Converting C to nasm assembly in 16 bit

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, x86-16

I try to convert my c code in assembly with gcc and objconv with:

```
bash -c "gcc -m16 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -s -c -o callBIOS.inc ../project/kernel/bootloader/callBIOS.c"
%objconv% -fnasm callBIOS.inc
```

but when I open it, it is write:

```
; Disassembly of file: callBIOS.inc
; Wed Feb 10 18:48:17 2021
; Mode: 32 bits
; Syntax: YASM/NASM
; Instruction set: 80386



SECTION .text   align=1 execute                         ; section number 1, code


SECTION .data   align=1 noexecute                       ; section number 2, data


SECTION .bss    align=1 noexecute                       ; section number 3, bss
```

and the mode here is the 32 bit, I need it in 16 bit. I  wonder if you could help me to covert my c to nasm assembly in 16 bits instead of 32 bits.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438244/gcc-compiles-16-bit-real-time-code-with-m16-option

Comment: That does make 16-bit code, but it still puts it in a normal 32-bit ELF `.o`. So unless you override the default, disassemblers with "incorrectly" disassemble it assuming 32-bit mode.  That's why the disassembly won't make sense, although you didn't bother to show it in your question.  BTW, you almost certainly don't want `-s` (strip) if you're going to disassemble; more metadata is better.

Comment: @Ruslan: It's not an exact duplicate; the OP has found the `-m16` option but hasn't understood exactly what it does.  Not sure if the answers there explain it in enough detail to help the OP understand why a disassembler chooses to disassemble as 32-bit mode. (See my previous comment, which I think is the answer although the question doesn't show actual disassembly so I didn't post it as such.)